# simulate a random walk in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

hello this is what i have done
[image]

I got done to point F

What I lack and I don't know how to do it is the last point (G)

since something like this has to come out

Can you help me with this last point, pls?

[image]
my code:

```
clc;clear;close all;
x=zeros; %store all x
y=zeros; %store all y
cx=0; %current x
cy=0; %current y
for i=1:20
x1 = rand(1); %generate random value
x2 = rand(1); %generate random value
s = 100*log(x1); %step size
angle = 2*pi*x2;
dx = s*cos(angle); %step size along x
cx = cx+dx; %new x position
dy = s*sin(angle); %step size along y
cy = cy+dy; %new y position
x = [x cx]; %add to array
y = [y cy]; %add to array


end

plot(x,y); %plot

title('Random Walk');
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
```

Comment: What is exactly that you "don't know how to do"? What have you tried?

Comment: Related but not exactly a dupe: [Variance in random Walk with Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58308918/8239061)

Answer (score 1):

### Plotting 3 Trajectories with 20 Movements Each

Using another outer for-loop can allow you to repeat the entire cycle. To plot multiple plots on the same axis add `hold on`.

[image: Random Walk Plot]

```
clc;clear;close all;

Number_Of_Trajectories = 3;
for Trajectory = 1: Number_Of_Trajectories
x= zeros; %store all x
y= zeros; %store all y
cx=0; %current x
cy=0; %current y


for Step = 1: 20
x1 = rand(1); %generate random value
x2 = rand(1); %generate random value
s = 100*log(x1); %step size
angle = 2*pi*x2;
dx = s*cos(angle); %step size along x
cx = cx+dx; %new x position
dy = s*sin(angle); %step size along y
cy = cy+dy; %new y position
x = [x cx]; %add to array
y = [y cy]; %add to array
end

plot(x,y); %plot
hold on

end


Limit = 1000; 

axis([-Limit Limit -Limit Limit]);
grid on;
title('Random Walk');
xlabel('X')
ylabel('Y')
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**